# Cache control using Meta Vs Headers

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, meta

I don't have web-server under my control

So to avoid cache i'm using this
`<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">`

but, this seems to be over-ridden by server `E-Tag` verification.

**Response Headers**

`ETag:W/"149774-1502468306000"
Expires:Thu, 16 Aug 2018 10:25:33 GMT
Last-Modified:Fri, 11 Aug 2017 16:18:26 GMT`

So, is their any way i can avoid the page from getting cached on client. I don't have access over Web server to change the header policy.

Answer (score 0):

No way to change the cache behavior without access to the Web server up to now.

1. "meta http-equiv" doesn't have a value "Cache-Control" according to [MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) and [HTML5 Doc](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element)
2. "meta http-equiv" is a strange attribute

   MDN Doc said:

   > can alter server and user-agent behavior.

   HTML4 Doc said

   > HTTP servers use this attribute to gather information for HTTP response message headers.

   HTML5 document said

   > it is an enumerated attribute ... lists the keywords defined for this attribute

   Such keywords like **http-equiv="refresh"**, can be used in client.

I think it's a poor design in html that wants to work out of HTTP but uncompleted.

Comment: Are you sure `meta http-equiv` are for server not for client ? I'm not able to find any source where i can confirm this. I'm also not sure about this, uptill now i was thinking its for client browser.

Comment: Im sorry I was misled. "http-equiv can alter server and user-agent behavior" said by MDN. We can't tell http-equiv="Cache-Control"  work for client or server

Comment: my opinion 2 is right, because http-equiv doesn't contains "Cache-Control" option